# Is there an where method in java like python

Tags: java, python, arraylist

IN python,if you want to get which index in x equals 2
you can do

```
x = [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,11] 
x=np.array(x)
np.where(x == 2)
```

but is there any simple way to do the same effect in java arraylist?
i want find all index in x equal to given condition

In java i only find indexof method but it can not work

here is my java code:

```
public class List_demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s1=1;
        int s2=2;
        int s3=2;
        int s4=2;
        List list=new ArrayList();
        list.add(s1);
        list.add(s2);
        list.add(s3);
        list.add(s4);
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why can `indexOf()` "not work" if you're just looking for the "index of" an element?

Comment: This is a third-party library in python, numpy

Answer (score 2):

you can use stream filter to pass your filter condition in your list

```
list.stream().filter(x -> /*your codition here, e.g: x == 2*/).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
integers.add(0);
int targetIndex;
```

Any of these will do, but there's no reason indexOf shouldn't work.

```
targetIndex = integers.indexOf(0);
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < integers.size(); i++) {
    if (integers.get(i) == 0) {
        targetIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

```
targetIndex = IntStream.range(0, integers.size())
        .filter(i -> integers.get(i).equals(0))
        .findFirst()
        .getAsInt();
```